# If an NP-hard problem is a special case of problem A, can we conclude problem A is NP-hard?

Tags: np-complete

Problem B is a special case of Problem A (problem A has additional variables $v_{additional}$ in comparison to problem B). This means for a specific value of $v_{additional}$, problem A is exactly the same as problem B. We know problem B is NP-hard. Can we conclude problem A is also NP-hard?

Comment: Yes. Fix an NP problem P. Since B is NP-hard, any instance of P can be reduced to an instance of B in polynomial time. But every instance of B is at the same time an instance of A. So we can reduce instance of P to A.

Comment: Is $v_{additional}$ always the same fixed value or might it depend on the B-problem hidden in the A-problem? In the lattre case, if the size grows fast enough in the size of the B-problem, it may be possible to have a polynomial algorithm for A that  still would produce an exponential algorithm for B

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: Problem B has $n$ inputs, problem A has $2n$ inputs. The extra $n$ variables are some kind of weight which can take any number. If  0 is assigned to these $n$ weights, problem A turns to B.  These weights in general can be any number and do not depend on B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "additional variable" do you mean "additional parameter"?  That is, 
an instance of $A$ specifies a value of $v_{additional}$, and for each instance of $B$ there is an instance of $A$ (with the value of $v_{additional}$ depending in a known way on the instance of $B$) such that the solutions of these instances of $A$ and $B$ are the same?

To expand slightly on Hagen's idea:

Suppose there is an algorithm that solves problem $B$ in time $T(n)$ where $n$ is the size of the instance.  Let an instance of $A$ consist of an instance of $B$ plus an additional parameter $v_{additional}$ which does nothing but take up space, in fact $T(n)$ bits of space.  Thus the size of this instance of $A$ is $n + T(n)$.  Then problem $A$ is in the class $P$: an algorithm of linear time complexity in the size of the instance consists of throwing away $v_{additional}$ and solving the instance of $B$.

Comment: Problem B has $n$ parameters, problem A has $2n$ parameters. The extra $n$ parameters are some kind of weight which can take any number. If 0 is assigned to these $n$ weights, problem A turns to B. These weights in general can be any number and do not depend on B. Problem B is actually maximum coverage problem.

Comment: In that case Wojowu's comment applies.

Comment: Problem B is an instance of A, however A is not an instance of B. So I don't think Wojowu's comment applies here. I cannot reduce B to A

Comment: If every instance of B is an instance of A (with the $n$ extra parameters set to 0), that **is** a polynomial-time reduction from B to A.